# Параллельные вычисления RecursiveAction

Tags: java

Я получаю данные с каншины автомобиля, в большом объеме и несколько раз за секунду. Код "получения" простой

```
private final UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
        try {
            SqrtTransform task = new SqrtTransform(arg0);
            task.invoke();
            if (mHandler != null) {
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT, arg0).sendToTarget();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException | InternalError e) {
        }
    }
};
```

Мне за один раз приходит массив byte. содержащий несколько сообщений (1 сообщение - 16 байт данных). Через *SqrtTransform task* я сделал распараллеливание вычислений и обработки

```
class SqrtTransform extends RecursiveAction {
    byte[] data;

    SqrtTransform(byte[] arg00) {
        data = arg00;
    }

    protected void compute() {
        try {
            if (data.length == 16) {
                _send_ID_byte(data);
            } else {
                // Здесь разбиваем на маленькие части
                // так неправильно и не работает параллельность
                int i2 = 0;
                while (i2 < data.length / 16) {
                    invokeAll(new SqrtTransform(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i2 * 16, 16 + i2 * 16)));
                    ++i2;
                }
                // так правильно и работает параллельность. Пример чисто теоретический
                invokeAll(new SqrtTransform_byte(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 0 * 16, 16 + 0 * 16)),
                          new SqrtTransform_byte(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 1 * 16, 16 + 1 * 16)),
                          new SqrtTransform_byte(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 2 * 16, 16 + 2 * 16)));
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь *_send_ID_byte(data)* это дальнейшая конечная обработка сигнала, с расшифровкой и записью по нужным данным, с несколькими отдельными функциями.

Правильно я оформил код? И будут ли функции в *_send_ID_byte(data)* так же выполняться в параллельном потоке?

P.S. Код немного неверный, внёс исправления